# Memory handling for OSX vs RPi

Tags: python, macos, raspberry-pi3, ram

Have a question that I can’t seem to find the answer to. So I have been using a raspberry pi to automate some scripts for data pulling in SQL databases. One issue that came up a few times was my python process gets killed which from the logs it looks like it’s due to insufficient RAM. This is from a raspberry pi 3B+, so only 1gb of ram. My question then is, is there a difference between say running it on a 1gb OSX system? Is there like better RAM management like writing swap files to the hard drive that another operating system/CPU architecture would have in this scenario? Or is it being a python process that the operating system cannot affect directly like that?

Note: this is really just for my understanding of how these factors work. I am pretty sure writing the code to process the data in chunks would work as a workaround to the RPi.

Comment: You may also use a `/swap` on the rpi?

Comment: I think when I was looking up swap files for the RPi, there was a lot about how this would really degrade SD card quickly. But was mostly curious if having the swap file would in fact prevent python from being killed due to insufficient ram?